# How to stop execution after certain time in java

Tags: java

I am trying to add a retry logic to a step in java. Using timers, I am able to repeat this step after certain time. However, in case the step doesn't get executed successfully, timer waits till the execution stops. My requirement is that I need to stop execution of this step after say 30s and then retry this logic.

Below is what I am trying to do.

Description of the step: I will call method processRequest by providing a Json input. This step gets executed successfully Everytime and returns a job Id. I am polling a url to get response to the provided job Id. This step sometimes doesn't get executed successfully or takes lot of time to return response. I want to terminate this task of polling and retry to call processRequest again which generates a new job Id and this has to be sent for polling. This logic has to get executed 5 times after waiting for 30s.

```
     Json request={operation:resize};
     String JOBID=processRequest(request);
     String response=http://pollingUrl/JOBID;
```

Can I do this without extending my class to Thread class or please suggest if there's anything else to achieve the same.

I am looking for something like this:

```
    String response="";
    Int count=5;
    While (count>0)
    {
       String JOBID=processRequest(request);
       String response=http://pollingUrl/JOBID; // terminate step after 30s
       If response !="";
       Return response; // return response and stop the while loop.
    }
```

Comment: If you're literally doing a network request, then I'd think that there's a way to configure your networking layer to time out.  That way would seem more robust and standardized.  Can you supply more information about what you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to use `Thread.sleep()`.  Assuming that you don't mind locking up your program for 30 seconds, you can do the following:

```java
    String response="";
    int count=5;
    While (count>0) {
        String JOBID=processRequest(request);
        String response=http://pollingUrl/JOBID;

        if (!response.equals("")) {
          return response; // return response and stop the while loop.
        }
        try {
          Thread.sleep(6000); // 6 seconds
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}

        count--;
    }
```

Note that the above won't work unless the http polling call is non-blocking.  That is, if it waits internally until a response is provided, it won't work.  But usually when polling calls are done there should be a mechanism to timeout at some point.

EDIT:  I changed two things.  I moved the sleep *after* the test for a response. And I modified how you were testing for equality (which may have been part of the problem). Use `equals` and not `==` or `!=` for comparing Strings.

Comment: I don't like `Thread.sleep()`.  If you want to go that route, use `java.util.Timer` instead.

Comment: Hi WJS -this particular http polling doesn't get timed out automatically. It waits for the response forever.

Comment: Then there must be a way to configure a timeout using the related API of the http call.  Otherwise, the polling service wouldn't be much use.  And remember that you were not comparing Strings correctly in your example.  Are you certain the request blocks?  In fact, I would suggest you re-edit your question to include the exact syntax you are using to check on the response.

Comment: Hi WJS- Thank you for looking into this. Actually, the logic i have written above is just a sample. The code that i am using is syntactically correct. My issue is only with terminating the polling step if it exceeds 30s. this API is an external one . I dont have access to change any configuration inside the API. I can only use it.

Comment: Hi markspace, using timer, i am not able to terminate the particular step of polling. Timer also waits till i receive some response from the polling api and this API doesnt get timed out automatically.