# How to stop execution of a step in Java after defined time duration

Tags: java, multithreading, http, timer

I am trying to add a retry logic to a step in java. Using timers, I am able to repeat this step after certain time. However, in case the step doesn't get executed successfully, timer waits till the execution stops. My requirement is that I need to stop execution of this step after say 30s and then retry this logic.

Below is what I am trying to do.

Description of the step: I will call method processRequest by providing a Json input. This step gets executed successfully Everytime and returns a job Id. I am polling a url to get response to the provided job Id. This step sometimes doesn't get executed successfully or takes lot of time to return response. I want to terminate this task of polling and retry to call processRequest again which generates a new job Id and this has to be sent for polling. This logic has to get executed 5 times after waiting for 30s. (Please ignore all the syntax errors if any. These are taken care of in the actual code)

```
 Json request={operation:resize};
 String JOBID=processRequest(request);
 String response=http://pollingUrl/JOBID;
```

Can I do this without extending my class to Thread class or please suggest if there's anything else to achieve the same.

I am looking for something like this:

```
String response="";
Int count=5;
While (count>0)
{
   String JOBID=processRequest(request);
   String response=http://pollingUrl/JOBID; // terminate step after 30s because this doesnt get terminated automatically
   If response !="";
   Return response; // return response and stop the while loop.
}
```

Comment: I understand this is pseudo-code.  But what libraries are you using for the http requests?  For instance, if SpringBoot, there are the Hystrix to handle faulty connections and the RestTemplate to control timeouts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop execution after certain time in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474751/how-to-stop-execution-after-certain-time-in-java)